# What do the first lines of a code in assembly mean?

Tags: assembly

```
pushl %ebp      
movl %esp, %ebp
```

This is my understanding:

1. Moves to the top of the stack. However, I'm not sure what is in %ebp or what gets stored in %ebp register.
2. If I use the basic understanding of this %esp is Sourche and %ebp is destination. So I'm moving what's in register %esp into register %ebp. What is in register %esp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention, esp is the stack pointer and ebp is the frame pointer. See [Intel x86 Function-call Conventions - Assembly View](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html).

So, by this convention, when a call is made, the current frame pointer (ebp, the frame pointer of the caller) is preserved (so that it can be restored when returning to the caller - so from the caller's perspective its frame pointer never changes). Then the current stack pointer (esp) is stored in ebp, making it the frame pointer for the called code.

Comment: Thats only partially true: the site you point to implies that stack frames are required all the time, thats incorrect, they are only needed when dynamic adjustment to esp occurs, either from VLA's, `_alloca`, re-alignment or unsafe functions like those with inline assembly in non-naked functions(under msvc) or where potential buffer over/under flows may occur and stack checking is enforced. In all other cases compilers can precalculate adjustments to esp and avoid frames(msvc has done this since at least v5)

Comment: Of course, I by no way implied that all code on earth works the way I described. I just linked to an article explaining that specific convention which was posted in the question and then elaborated a bit, explicitly starting with _"by this convention, ..."_ That this convention is not always followed is a different story (and the reasons are many, you mention a few but there are more - just consider non-x86 architectures).

Answer (score 0):

`%esp` is the current stackpointer, ie. the top of it. `%ebp` represents the base pointer of the current function. It is needed so the function knows where its stack begins. You need to save the previous function's `%ebp` (`pushl %ebp`) to the stack to be able to assign your own.

Later, when going up the stack again, each function will have its base pointer restored to be able continue working.

Answer (score 0):

```
    pushl %ebp      
    movl %esp, %ebp
```

- save ebp register on the stack
- move (copy) the content of register esp into the register ebp

The "style" of the piece of code is so that source is the first argument and destination the second; in the intel style you would see something like

```
    push ebp
    mov  ebp, esp
```

This is the plain explanation of those lines of code. The meaning depends. Usually it is a common prolog for functions generated by a high level language (e.g. C), respecting some calling convention. The epilog should look like

```
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

Room for local variables can be "created" on stack by decrementing esp, and using ebp to access the data, preserving the normal usage of esp e.g. for another call to another function (return address is pushed on stack), and avoiding overwriting of the local variables: the memory between the decremented esp and the base ebp is something like a "reserved area" on stack that the current function can use.

Since each entered function preserve both ebp and esp, recursive function call (until the stack limit is reached) are rather natural in this calling convention mechanism, and nested function can be called *ad libitum* (until the stack ends!).